# Отслеживание касания пустой области экрана Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, touch-event, unity3d-faq

Как реализовать в 2D проекте Unity отслеживание нажатия (OnPointerDown в EventTrigger) в области Canvas с учётом того, что на экране могут отображаться ещё и другие элементы (кнопки настройки, паузы и т.п.)? Как в Geometry Dash, Knife Hit, Crossy Road и других подобных играх, где используются ни джойстики и кнопки.

Я попробовал использовать Panel для этого, закинув на него EventTrigger с добавлением пары событий, но ничего не срабатывает. Без компонента Imagine на Button также ничего не срабатывает

Comment: Можно сделать прозрачный рисунок, а можно написать свой компонент реагирующий на касание. Я сейчас наверняка не скажу, но в интернете точно уже есть ответ на этот вопрос как именно реализовать свой компонент. Как минимум потому что я его задавал несколько лет назад :) Но не помню где

Comment: Да, я уже это сделал. Всё отлично работает :)

Comment: тебе повезло, по чистой случайности мне на имейл пришло сообщение как раз из мною заданного вопроса на эту тему) Оставляю самый оптимальный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать Panel, Image, Button, Empty Object или любой другой объект, на котором есть компонент Image. На него нужно добавить компонент Event Trigger и выбрать нужные события. После этого вся область, занимаемая объектом, будет обрабатываться Event Trigger-ом

Answer (score 0):

Самым оптимальным решением является создать обьект `Text` внутри Канваса, очистить сам текст и проставить галочку "Raycast Target"

Ответ взят отсюда: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1157876/view.html

---

Данное решение более оптимальное чем использование прозрачной картинки или кнопки и не требует дополнительного написания скриптов, а так же, в отличии от "пустых картинок" не пытается дергать прорисовку на канавасе. Как следствие имеет лучшее быстродействие.